# Given two dynamic R x C matrixes, how can I interleave the rows to produce one 2R x C matrix?

Tags: c++, eigen

Using [eigen2](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-2.0/), and given a matrix A

```
a_0_0, a_0_1, a_0_2, ...
a_1_0, a_1_0, a_1_2, ...
...
```

and a matrix B:

```
b_0_0, b_0_1, b_0_2, ...
b_1_0, b_1_1, b_1_2, ...
...
```

and where A and B have the same dimensions, I would like to interleave the rows, producing:

```
a_0_0, a_0_1, a_0_2, ...
b_0_0, b_0_1, b_0_2, ...
a_1_0, a_1_0, a_1_2, ...
b_1_0, b_1_1, b_1_2, ...
...
```

Obviously I can write a function that will construct an output matrix of the proper dimensions, then loop over each of the input matrices and assign elements to the result. I'd rather not re-invent the wheel though, so if eigen2 already has a mechanism to express this sort of matrix surgery elegantly I'd much prefer to use it.

I did look through the eigen2 docs and nothing jumped out at me as obviously correct. The closest thing I found was MatrixBase::select, but that does 'element from a or element from b', where what I want is 'element from a then element from b in the next row'.

Efficiency is not of paramount concern since I don't need to do this in the fast path, only at initialization.

I apologize for the formatting if there is a better way to represent matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply each R x C matrix by a 2R x R matrix consisting of zeroes and ones on the appropriate diagonal, then add.

Matrix 1

```
1 0 0 0 ...
0 0 0 0 ...
0 1 0 0 ...
0 0 0 0 ...
```

Matrix 2

```
0 0 0 0 ...
1 0 0 0 ...
0 0 0 0 ...
0 1 0 0 ...
```

Comment: Interesting idea, though something seems slightly off, since I can't multiply a RxC by a 2RxR matrix, since the inner dimensions don't match, and even if they did, I would get an RxR result, not 2RxC. In addition, the complexity of building your 'alternator' matrices is exactly as complex as performing interleave of the identity and zero matrices, so I'd need to run the loop at least once to produce them. But I really like where this idea is going, since I could cache the 'alternator' matrixes and re-use them.

Comment: If you swap the matrices around, e.g., (Matrix 1 * a) + (Matrix 2 * b) it will work.

Comment: Ah, right. My linear algebra teacher is frowning at me from somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: If you're using Eigen3 and you want to do these via matrix multiplication at least use a sparse matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is specific to Eigen3, but you can interleave rows using the `Map` and `Stride` objects.

```
MatrixXi C(A.rows()+B.rows(),A.cols());
Map<MatrixXi,0,Stride<Dynamic,2> >(C.data(),A.rows(),A.cols(),Stride<Dynamic,2>(2*A.rows(),2)) = A;
Map<MatrixXi,0,Stride<Dynamic,2> >(C.data()+1,B.rows(),B.cols(),Stride<Dynamic,2>(2*B.rows(),2)) = B;
```

[source](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=3724)